# RSS feed of hot questions

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, feed, hot-questions

https://stackexchange.com/feeds/questions

The [RSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) feed items has the title of:
`question title - se site`
and it has `from` field `username of original poster`

When I subscribe to this RSS feed (using [Thunderbird](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Thunderbird)), all I see is a huge title and the username of the poster, and most of the time the `se site` part is trimmed.

This makes it very hard if I quickly want to scan through sites that looks interesting to me, and I want to ignore sites that are not of interest to me.

This is easy to do from a Stack Exchange site, through the top left corner Stack Exchange link, since the site name is separated on a different line.

---

- Is it possible to have the `from` field say the `se site` instead of the `username`?
  (Since the username is of no interest to me in this situation, although it might break the standard.)
- Is it possible to have the `title` formated in which the `se site` comes first before the question title? (The title would be `se site - question title`.)

Answer (score 2):

It turned out to be possible to use [Yahoo Pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Pipes) to process the RSS feeds, and output exactly what I need.